# A question about Cartan subalgebra

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have a semisimple lie algebra $\mathcal{G}$, let $A$ be its element such that under the eigen equation 
$$[A,X]=\rho X,\ X\in\mathcal{G},$$
$A$ has maximal number of eigenvalues. Now we know that only the eigenspace corresponding to eigenvalue 0 can be degenerate. 
Suppose the eigenspace with eigenvalue 0 is spaned by $\{H_i\}, i=1,...,r$. My question is how can we prove that the space $\{H_i\}$ is abelian? That is, how to prove
$$[H_i,H_j]=0$$
for any $i,j=1,...,r$ ?

Answer (score 0):

By definition a Cartan subalgebra is a maximal *toral* subalgebra, i.e., consists of semisimple elements (one has to show this in case one uses a different definition of Cartan subalgebra). But any toral subalgebra is abelian - see for example [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&ved=0ahUKEwj1mIm4lYbUAhXDWBQKHa31BJkQFghyMAk&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.upenn.edu%2F~brweber%2FCourses%2F2012%2FMath650%2FNotes%2FL11_CartanSubAlg.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFx8lZRaNrxmZujBiXUZ1BKYyc-ug&sig2=ZLXph2Y71V0sZuCHO4ztmA).

Comment: Could you please give a proof along the line that the eigenspace of eigenvalue 0 is abelian?

Comment: The $H_i$'s are semsiimple, hence diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$. So they commute.

Comment: What do you mean by ``The $H_i$'s are semisimple"? How to see that this subalgebra is semisimple. Further why is a semisimple algebra is abelian (this seems to be rather contradict with the definition of semisimple)?

Comment: No, not semisimple Lie algebra. I mean, $H_i$ is a semisimple *element* of a Lie algebra. Here semisimple (as a matrix) means that it is diagonalizable over $C$ - see [Jordan-Chevalley decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%E2%80%93Chevalley_decomposition).

Comment: Then the question is translated to why are $H_i$'s semisimple...,If you can give a proof with lines of equations, I would appreciate that very much.

Comment: These are elements $ad(h_i)$, where $ad(h_i)(x)=[h_i,x]$, which are semisimple because $H$ is a Cartan subalgebra (somewhere you need to use that we have a Cartan subalgebra).